# How add php locale on windows 10

Tags: php, windows, laravel, locale

If I install my project locally on windows 10, I want add locale to windows such as in ubuntu:

```
sudo locale-gen uk_UA.utf8
sudo update-locale
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
echo "Europe/Kyiv" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
```

for example. How I can do it on windows environment?

Comment: You have [Regional Settings](http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/windows-10-change-country-or-region1.png) in Windows 10, and also there's a setting for [Date & Time](http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/time-and-language.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You do it using [**Regional Settings**](https://support.microsoft.com/hub/4338813/windows-help) for setting the locale:

> **To change the country or region setting**
>
> 1. Open Region and Language by clicking the **Start** button [image]
>      , clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Clock, Language, and Region**, and then clicking **Region and Language**.
> 2. Click the **Location** tab, select your location from the list, and then click **OK**.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ilovefreesoftware.com](http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/windows-10-change-country-or-region1.png))</sub>

And to change the time zone, on the same page, you have Date and Time. Click that.

[image]

This should have been a question in the Super User.

Comment: Praveen, i want that date of php render in other language on windows env

Comment: Praveen Kumar, I can't do it!

Comment: @IslamKhandurdyiev Why?

Comment: i don't know. I tried. But from your answer i not all understand.

Comment: I use php function setlocale(LC_ALL, 'uk_UA.utf8') and I want that my site show date format on different languages, but how i can do it in windows env?

Comment: @IslamKhandurdyiev It works for me. I don't understand why doesn't it work for you.

Comment: @IslamKhandurdyiev Can you use Vagrant?